# Login failed SQL client in local

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a problem. I have created a web setup for my ASP.NET application, which also includes database, and SQL Server Express and .NET framework.

Now when I install the software it checks if the .NET framework and SQL Server Express are present, and if not, it will install those items.

When application starts, it will check to see if the database is present and if not, it will install it.

Now the problem is that when I open the application it gives me an error:

> login failed for username/ASP.NET

Can anybody help me in how we can install the SQL clients in desktops and it will connect with our application without setting any username and passwords?

All I have do via coding not manually

Answer (score 1):

Remote connections are disabled by default. You can use the Surface Area Configuration tool to enable them.

You can find the complete answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/b1fad2ef-305c-4e30-8b05-e126e659478b/